# IIS MVC/WCF Certificate authentication on specified pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, authentication, iis

The problem I am facing is that I only want the clients (end users) to present a certificate on specified pages within the MVC/WCF application.
When I set the IIS options "Client certificates = Accept" the site always requires a certificate when browsed, shouldn't be this way when setting the option to "Required" ?
Googled for a while but web.config configurations to override the IIS certificate check and only do certificate check on certain pages does not turn up many results.
In a simplified way what I want to accomplish is:

1. User browses Home page
2. Reads some news articles
3. Goes to a page that requires authentication
4. Make the user/client present a certificate
5. Here on I will make some checks to the certificate programatically (this bit I have solved)

I don't provide any code cause I don't have any, everything I have is the certificate option in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer.
Location tag and in the applicationHost.config allow override the "access" section

applicationHost.config

```
                <section name="access" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

Application web.config

```
<location path="PathToSvcFile.svc">
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <authentication>
      <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true"/>
    </authentication>
    <access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert"/>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```